# C# TableAdapter optional WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have a query like this made in QueryBuilder:

```
SELECT Items    FROM     Tables
WHERE  (Transactions.transaction_type = ? AND
Items.designation LIKE '%'+?+'%' AND Transactions.transaction_date >= ?
AND Transactions.transaction_date <= ? AND Items.item_number = ?)
```

Later using it something like this:

```
this.TransactionItemsReportTableAdapter.Fill(this.InventoryDataSet.TransactionItemsReport, 10,
"", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue, 0);
```

However I don't always want to filter by item_number, therefore: Is it possible to either ignore the WHERE clause temporarily or set a null value (like in the designation argument) without creating a separate query in the designer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT Items FROM Tables
WHERE Transactions.transaction_type = @TransatctionType AND
Items.designation LIKE '%'+ @Designation +'%'
AND Transactions.transaction_date >= @DateFrom
AND Transactions.transaction_date <= @DateTo 
AND (@ItemNumber IS NULL OR Items.item_number = @ItemNumber)
```

What is the reason for not creating an new query? The code is more maintainable in this case.